# Bullets MarkerStyle with C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently trying to figure out a way to change the Bullet MarkerStyle when EditingCommands.ToggleBullets is executed. From what I understand CommandManager.Execute is executed before the togglebullets is done. So I am unable to simply go in and change the List.MarkerStyle with the ExecutedRoutedEvent.
Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this? Another thing I was trying to see if I could even change the default MarkerStyle but didn't see any way to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can change a List's default MarkerStyle in xaml:

```
<List MarkerStyle=Square>
    <ListItem>Item with a square</ListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or include a style in your resources which will change all MarkerStyle properties for you:

```
<Style TargetType="List">
    <Setter Property="MarkerStyle" Value="Square" />
</Style>
```